# Python Socket OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

Hi guys I am trying to create a TCP chat room these are my code

```
import threading
import socket


host = '0.0.0.0' #Local Host

port = 55555

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((host,port))

server.listen()
```

But  when I run its it is showing`OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use`

I have try`ps -fA | grep python`  to kill an existing process but still getting a same error.Please help me

Comment: If you want to bind to only localhost, then that's the address `127.0.0.1`. Or if you want to bind to the wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY`) then use an empty string `''`.

Comment: Also, are there other program (not Python scripts, but any other program) which is already bound to the same address? Considering your use of `ps` and `grep` I assume you're on a POSIX-like system (like Linux), then use [`netstat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html) to get information about programs listening on port `55555`.

Comment: Lastly you might want to learn more about [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), especially [the possible socket states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#/media/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg). The `TIME WAIT` state can last for up to a couple of minutes, during which time no other programs can bind to the same address. Try just waiting a few minutes and try again. If it works then learn about the `SO_REUSEADDR` option.

Comment: Does it happen with other ports?

Comment: maybe other program (not Python script) use it. If script was working at first start then system may keep this port for some time - it may think that previous program is only sleeping and it will still use this port. You may need `server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` before `bind`. and it may need `server.close()` at the end.

Comment: minimal [example with comments](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/socket/basic/version-1/server.py) - version without `threading`